# QuickTime MOV embedded in HTML page: Can't get controls to appear

Tags: html, embed, quicktime, mov

Video plays fine, but the controls (play, stop, rewind etc.) don't appear, despite setting the "controller" parameter to "true".

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="320" height="260">
<param name="src" value="myvid.mov" />
<param name="controller" value="true" />
<object type="video/quicktime" data="myvid.mov" width="320" height="260" class="mov">
<param name="controller" value="true" />
</object>
</object>
```

Works fine when I refer to this video:

http://realdev1.realise.com/rossa/rendertest/quicktime.html

Do the controls need to be enabled when encoding the video perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The height of the movie + 16px should do the trick.